# I am trying use tag in my Cucumber runner but doesn't work. I am new to Cucumber

Tags: java, junit, cucumber

[Please see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGy3t.png)I am trying to run my cucumber runner with cucumber options and trying to use tags, but it doesn't work.

```
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        dryRun = false,
        strict = true,
        monochrome = true,
        features = {"src/test/resources/"},
        glue = {"com.learning"},
        plugin = {"pretty",
                "html:target/site/cucumber-html",
                "json:target/cucumber1.json"},
        tags = {"@BookingFlight"}
)
public class MyRunner {

}

Error is: java: annotation value not of an allowable type[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6OuL.png
```

Comment: Removing the curly brackets around tags value should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the curly brackets in tags attribute:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        dryRun = false,
        strict = true,
        monochrome = true,
        features = {"src/test/resources/"},
        glue = {"com.learning"},
        plugin = {"pretty",
                "html:target/site/cucumber-html",
                "json:target/cucumber1.json"},
        tags = "@BookingFlight"
)
public class MyRunner {

}
```

You can specify more than one tag in a single string, i.e.: "@BookingFlight or @BookingGeneral"

Comment: Thank you for answering the question @Xavier Rusiñol Escriu